# ADO Entity Framework Diagram problems 

Tags: entity-framework

### Environment:

- Windows Vista x64
- Visual Studio 2008 Pro Edition 9.0.30729.1 SP
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1

### Problem:

1. Blank Entity Framework Diagrams can be opened but no tables can be dropped into the diagram from the Data Connections or ...
2. Entity Framework Diagrams can be populated with "generate from database" option but then diagrams will not open.

The generated option opens in XML editor and is populated with the associated data.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same problem... The only work around that I have found is to open with the Xml editor first (when I can't open it in the EDM designer) and the close it and turn around and re-open it up in the EDM designer.